# Arbitrage Trading of ETH/BTC using ccxt crypto API throws error while creating buy order

Tags: php, cryptocurrency, ccxt

I am working on an app that does **ETH/BTC** arbitrage trading of crypto-currency using ccxt crypto API for PHP, and i keep receiving this **Network Error** exception thrown from the API call usually while trying to place a limit buy order.

```
{"status":-124,"error_message":"Enter the size in units of 0.0000001 ETH.","data":null}
```

This above exception is thrown from Bitflyer exchange.

My code is as follows:

```
$name = '\\ccxt\\'.$exchangeId;
$exchange = new $name(array (
    'apiKey'          => $api_key, // ←------------ replace with your keys
    'secret'          => $secret_key,
    'enableRateLimit' => true,
));

try{
   $symbol = 'ETH/BTC'; 
   $type = 'limit'; // # or 'market', or 'Stop' or 'StopLimit'
   $side = 'buy'; // 'sell' or 'buy'
   $amount = $data['trade_base_amount'];    //0.0515996
   $price  = $data['exchange_rate']; // 0.01938
   // extra params and overrides
   $params = array();

   $response = $exchange->create_order($symbol, $type, $side, $amount, $price, $params);
    print_r($response);
}catch (\ccxt\NetworkError $e) {
    echo $exchange->id . ' fetch_trades failed due to a network error: '.$e->getMessage () . "\n";
}catch (\ccxt\ExchangeError $e) {
    echo $exchange->id . ' fetch_trades failed due to exchange error: ' .$e->getMessage () . "\n";
}catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $exchange->id . ' fetch_trades failed with: ' . $e->getMessage () . "\n";
}
```

Can anyone please explain why am I getting this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: round the price to 0.0000001. in your case 0.0193800

Answer (score 0):

Try using amountToPrecision for me worked
get the documentation on CCXT

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).